# Routing table interpretation

Tags: networking

Given the following table, where the network is using 8-bit host addresses, I am asked to compute the associated range of destination host addresses for every interface. Then I am also asked about the number of addresses in every range.

```
Table:
prefix match         Interface
    00                  0
    010                 1
    011                 2
    10                  2
    11                  3
```

I determined that I am given the prefixes of the 8-bit binary IP's and the concluded that:

> 00000000 to 00111111 (0-63 in decimal) uses interface 0

addresses in the range = 2 to the power of (8 - the number of bits in the prefix, so 2) = 64

> 01000000 to 01011111 (64-95 in decimal) uses interface 1

addresses in range = 2^(8-3) = 32

> 01100000 to 10111111 (96-191 in decimal) uses interface 2

addresses in range = 2^5 = 32

> 11000000 and higer   (192+ in decimal) uses interface 3

addresses in range = 2^5 = 32

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Looks correct to me. What problem are you having with your answer?

Comment: I was wondering about the addresses in each range. 2^3 or 2^2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of addresses in each range is 2<sup>(8 - prefixlen)</sup>. So if the prefix has 2 bits, the number of addresses is 2<sup>6</sup> = 64.